Azure tts api about getting voice lists for Azure text to speech
Is there anything like API endpoint on Azure tts which provides voices data with sample voice url apart from this voices/list endpoint?
This gives a list of voices, but I want like azure portal which that I play audio sample which I want to here and than used to go with particular voice after hearing.
I tried by using tts endpoint by providing sample text but it uses credit which I don't want.
app.get('/api/voicegallery', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(https://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list, {
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey
            }
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
            const voices = response.data;
            // Example of transforming the response data if needed
            const voicesWithSamples = voices.voices.map(voice => ({
                name: voice.name,
                locale: voice.locale,
                gender: voice.gender,
                style: voice.style,
                sampleUrl: `https://your-cdn-or-service/${voice.name}/sample.mp3` // Modify as needed
            }));

            res.json(voicesWithSamples);
        } else {
            console.log('Azure API Response Status:', response.status);
            res.status(response.status).send('Error fetching voices.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching voices:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Error fetching voices.');
    }
});

